# Error Tibco business studio: "There is no Component in the Application Module"

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

After migrating BW project (5.x) on Tibco business studio, when I tried to run the process, I got the error: There is no Component in the Application Module

Then, I checked and found that:

> TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-600026: Failed to start BW Application
>   [demo.application:1.0]. Reason: TIBCO-BW-FRWK-600043: Invalid Module
>   [demo:1.0.0.qualifier]. There is no Component in the Application
>   Module. Contact TIBCO Support.

Please see my images:

1. Project after migrating
   [image]
2. Project tibco designer (before migrating)
   [image]

Do you know how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Your process must be in the "Processes" folder. Then add the component from Module Descriptors/Components tab.

The process must be a process with a starter not a sub process.[image]

Comment: Why didn't it auto migrate the process ?